# JavaFX bind PathTransition's element coordinates

Tags: javafx-8, property-binding

I'd like to have a path transition in such a way, that the path behaves relative to the window size, even when the size is changed during the animation. Furthermore, when the animation is completed, the animated element should use the stay at the relative destination location.

`tileWidthProperty` and `tileHeightProperty` are class members that I added for convinience and they simply divide the main pane's size in eights.

This is the code I have:

```
public void applyMove(final Ellipse toBeMoved, final int startCol, final int startRow, final int endCol, final int endRow)
{

    Platform.runLater(() ->
    {
        final Path path = new Path();

        final MoveTo startingPoint = new MoveTo();
        final LineTo endPoint = new LineTo();

        startingPoint.xProperty().bind(tileWidthProperty.multiply(startCol).add(tileWidthProperty.divide(2)));
        startingPoint.yProperty().bind(tileHeightProperty.multiply(startRow).add(tileHeightProperty.divide(2)));

        endPoint.xProperty().bind(tileWidthProperty.multiply(endCol).add(tileWidthProperty.divide(2)));
        endPoint.yProperty().bind(tileHeightProperty.multiply(endRow).add(tileHeightProperty.divide(2)));

        path.getElements().add(startingPoint);
        path.getElements().add(endPoint);

        toBeMoved.centerXProperty().unbind();
        toBeMoved.centerYProperty().unbind();

        PathTransition transition = new PathTransition(Duration.millis(10000), path, toBeMoved);
        transition.setOrientation(PathTransition.OrientationType.NONE);
        transition.setCycleCount(1);
        transition.setAutoReverse(false);

        //bind the node at the destination.
        transition.setOnFinished(event ->
        {
            toBeMoved.centerXProperty().bind(tileWidthProperty.multiply(endCol).add(tileWidthProperty.divide(2)));
            toBeMoved.centerYProperty().bind(tileHeightProperty.multiply(endRow).add(tileHeightProperty.divide(2)));
            toBeMoved.setTranslateX(0.0);
            toBeMoved.setTranslateY(0.0);
        });

        transition.play();
    });
}
```

The col and row parameters are integers that are known to be 0 <= x < 8. They are the column and row of the tile position in the 8*8 grid.

The binding of the MoveTo and LineTo elements, however does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: I could solve the issue regarding the destination after the transition by setting the ellipse's translation x and y values to 0. The animation itself is however still static and I still need help in that regard, although it might nor be that trivial, seeing that it just alters the translation rather than the position itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, once any standard `Animation` is started it **does not** change parameters.
So if anything changes, you have to stop the animation and start it again with new parameters.

I noticed you're trying to bind `centerX` and `centerY` after the transition is complete, which is wrong: `PathTransition` moves elements using `translateX` and `translateY`.

And for better debug you can actually add `Path` to the scene graph to see where your element will go.

```java
Path path = new Path();
parent.getChildren().add(path);
```

I assume that `tileWidthProperty` and `tileHeightProperty` are bound to the actual `parent` size using something like this:

```java
tileWidthProperty.bind(parent.widthProperty().divide(8));
tileHeightProperty.bind(parent.heightProperty().divide(8));
```

So I created example just to show how it might look like.

```java
import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application {

    private Pane parent;
    private final DoubleProperty
            tileWidthProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty(),
            tileHeightProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    private EllipseTransition ellipseTransition;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.parent = new Pane();

        tileWidthProperty.bind(parent.widthProperty().divide(8));
        tileHeightProperty.bind(parent.heightProperty().divide(8));

        // create ellipse
        final Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse(25., 25.);
        parent.getChildren().add(ellipse);

        // show the stage
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(parent, 800, 800));
        primaryStage.show();

        // create listeners that listen to size changes
        InvalidationListener sizeChangeListener = l -> {
            if(ellipseTransition != null) {
                // refreshAndStart returns null if transition is completed
                // let's call it delayed cleanup :)
                ellipseTransition = ellipseTransition.refreshAndStart();
            } else {
                System.out.println("ellipseTransition cleaned up!");
            }
        };
        // add listeners to the corresponding properties
        tileWidthProperty.addListener(sizeChangeListener);
        tileHeightProperty.addListener(sizeChangeListener);

        // move ellipse 0,0 -> 7,7
        applyMove(ellipse, 0, 0, 7, 7, Duration.millis(5000));

        // interrupt transition at the middle, just for fun
        /*new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            }
            applyMove(ellipse, 2, 3, 4, 5, Duration.millis(1000));
        }).start();*/
    }


    public void applyMove(final Ellipse toBeMoved, final int startCol, final int startRow, final int endCol, final int endRow, final Duration duration) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            // if transition is still up, then stop it
            if(ellipseTransition != null) {
                ellipseTransition.finish();
            }
            // and create a new one
            ellipseTransition = new EllipseTransition(toBeMoved, startCol, startRow, endCol, endRow, Duration.ZERO, duration, 0);
            // then start it
            ellipseTransition.start();
        });
    }

    // I decided to write separate class for the transition to make it more convenient
    private class EllipseTransition {
        // these variables are the same you used in your code
        private final Path path;
        private final Ellipse ellipse; // this one was "toBeMoved"
        private final int startCol, startRow, endCol, endRow;
        private final Duration duration;
        private final PathTransition transition;

        // if we change parent size in the middle of the transition, this will give the new transition information about where we were.
        private Duration startTime;

        // we call System.currentTimeMillis() when we start
        private long startTimestamp;

        // if true, transition would not start again
        private boolean finished;

        public EllipseTransition(Ellipse ellipse, int startCol, int startRow, int endCol, int endRow, Duration startTime, Duration duration, long realStartTimestamp) {
            this.path = new Path();
            this.ellipse = ellipse;
            this.startCol = startCol;
            this.startRow = startRow;
            this.endCol = endCol;
            this.endRow = endRow;
            this.startTime = startTime;
            this.duration = duration;
            this.transition = new PathTransition();

            // applyMove passes 0, because we don't know our start time yet
            this.startTimestamp = realStartTimestamp;
        }

        // this is called right before starting the transition
        private void init() {
            // show path for debugging
            parent.getChildren().add(path);

            // binding values here is useless, you can compute everything in old-fashioned way for better readability
            final MoveTo startingPoint = new MoveTo();
            startingPoint.setX(tileWidthProperty.get() * startCol + tileWidthProperty.get() / 2.);
            startingPoint.setY(tileHeightProperty.get() * startRow + tileHeightProperty.get() / 2.);

            final LineTo endPoint = new LineTo();
            endPoint.setX(tileWidthProperty.get() * endCol + tileWidthProperty.get() / 2);
            endPoint.setY(tileHeightProperty.get() * endRow + tileHeightProperty.get() / 2);

            path.getElements().clear(); // clear paths from the last time
            path.getElements().add(startingPoint);
            path.getElements().add(endPoint);

            ellipse.translateXProperty().unbind();
            ellipse.translateYProperty().unbind();

            transition.setNode(ellipse);
            transition.setDuration(duration);
            transition.setPath(path);
            transition.setOrientation(PathTransition.OrientationType.NONE);
            transition.setCycleCount(1);
            transition.setAutoReverse(false);

            transition.setOnFinished(event ->
            {
                // bind ellipse to the new location
                ellipse.translateXProperty().bind(tileWidthProperty.multiply(endCol).add(tileWidthProperty.divide(2)));
                ellipse.translateYProperty().bind(tileHeightProperty.multiply(endRow).add(tileHeightProperty.divide(2)));

                // cleanup
                stop();

                // mark as finished
                finished = true;
            });
        }

        // stops the transition
        private void stop() {
            // remove debug path ( added it in init() )
            parent.getChildren().remove(path);
            transition.stop();
        }

        // starts the transition
        public void start() {
            if(finished) {
                return;
            }

            init(); // initialize parameters

            // start from the place where previous we stopped last time
            // if we did not stop anywhere, then we start from beginning (applyMove passes Duration.ZERO)
            this.transition.playFrom(startTime);

            // applyMove passes 0, as it doesn't know when transition will start
            // but now we know
            if(this.startTimestamp == 0) {
                this.startTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
        }

        // stops the transition
        public void finish() {
            stop();
            finished = true;
        }

        // stops and refreshes the transition.
        // that will continue transition but for new values
        private void refresh() {
            // stop the transition
            stop();

            // determine how much time we spend after transition has started
            long currentDuration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTimestamp;

            // update startTime to the current time.
            // when we call start() next time, transition will continue, but with new parameters
            this.startTime = Duration.millis(currentDuration);
        }

        // this method is called from change listener
        public EllipseTransition refreshAndStart() {
            if(finished) {
                // return null to the listener
                // we want to cleanup completely
                return null;
            }
            // refresh new values and start
            refresh(); start();
            return this;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think of adding a listener to the properties, for whatever reason. It actually already works, when the listener gets the current Duration, stops the transition and restarts it, given that the points are bound with property binding.
Btw: you don't need to calculate the duration, `transition.getCurrentTime();` works as well.